# Python on write time show suggestions / hints from dict in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a possibility show of hints from dict in VSCODE?

```
class TestClassNew(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.obj = dict()
    
    def FormatKey(self, key : str, *args) -> str:
        if args:
            for k in args:
                key += "_{}"
            key = key.format(*args)
        return key
    
    def Set(self, key : str, value : None, *args) -> None:
        key = self.FormatKey(key, *args)
        self.obj[key] = value

    def Get(self, key : str, *args) -> object:
        key = self.FormatKey(key, *args)
        if key not in self.obj:
            return None
        return self.obj[key]

class MyClass():
    def Method1(self):
        pass
    def Method2(self):
        pass
    def Method3(self):
        pass

class Wnd(TestClassNew):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        a = MyClass()
        a.Method1()## WORK FINE

        self.Set("somekey", MyClass())
        self.Get("somekey").Method1() ## NO HINTS / SUGGESTION - not working
```

Local variable, hints display correctly:

[image: correct display]

From Dict hints are not displayed correctly:

[image: incorrect display]

Comment: You've annotated the `Get` method as returning a plain `object, the hints you get align with this. How is the IDE supposed to know what those methods do, they look nothing like the dict API?

Comment: why don't you make `TestClassNew` a `dict` subclass

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility show of hints from dict in VSCODE?

if you can use python version >= 3.8 you can try and use `TypedDict`.

See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) for more details.

Comment: The values in the question don't appear to have any specific type, however, and the keys seem to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary itself doesn't have types, so its not possible for any static type checker to know what options are available for the values, plus, your `Get` function is returning an `object` type, not `MyClass`, so wouldn't know to complete instance methods specific to that either

Keep in mind that Python syntax guide says to `snake_case` your methods, not capitalize them